# This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 85

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I have updated my Chrome to the latest 87.0.4280.67 version recently and I have a consecutive chromedriver downloaded too: ChromeDriver 87.0.4280.20 but my tests are failing with the error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message:
> session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome
> version 85

I've spent the whole day searching for similar problems/solutions here but nothing helps in my case.

I also looked at similar problems here, but they don't really help.

I can see in the logs below information:

[WDM] - Get LATEST driver version for 87.0.4280
[WDM] - Driver [/Users/nataliamarciniak/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/mac64/87.0.4280.20/chromedriver] found in cache

So to me, it seems the versions are alike - expected vs found.
Where the problem can be?

Comment: You do need to keep Chrome and chromedriver version in sync and my guess is that you have multiple chromedriver versions installed (virtual environments perhaps?). Running `chromedriver --version` in a command line terminal  would be the first step to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Are you sure you're referencing the correct chromedriver?

Comment: Yes, I am using the correct version for sure.

Comment: I am also seeing below:

[WDM] - Get LATEST driver version for 87.0.4280
[WDM] - Driver [/Users/nataliamarciniak/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/mac64/87.0.4280.20/chromedriver] found in cache

Would that be the case that I shouldn't use the '.20' in the chromedriver version?